# preg_match_all is outputting a blank array

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I am trying to extract the ip addresses out of a log file and I am getting an empty array.

Code:

```
$file = file('log.txt');
$ips = implode($fixed);

$pattern2 = "/[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}/";     
preg_match_all($pattern2, $ips, $m);
print_r($m[0]);
```

Example

```
$ips='http://localhost/articles/  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0 /articles/ 2-9-2016 17:55 24.100.248.111';
```

I tested the pattern at http://tryphpregex.com/ and it highlights just the ip address with the above string.

Also can preg_match_all accept values from an array? I didn't see anything in the php documentation about that.

I just took all the filtering logic out and the script works, apparently the filters  in the file to get rid of lines were getting rid of all the lines. *blush*. The output of $ips is

```
Array
    (
    [15] =>  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.73 Safari/537.36 OPR/34.0.2044.98679 /  172.56.35.178 

    [16] => http://localhost/ Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.73 Safari/537.36  OPR/34.0.2044.98679 /articles/automate-it-all/  172.56.35.178
```

Comment: Your regex doesn't work when I tested it on that site. But it worked with single ` \ ` instead of ` \\ `. Have you tested that?

Comment: Or you could use the single quote `'~[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}~'` The double escape's should be parsed to a single one with double quotations. If it didn't, that would be a problem.

Comment: Actually when I was trying to put the code into stackoverflow.com it was previewing without the backslashes, I tried it with the single escape character

Comment: Also I tried the ~ instead of the backslash as the delimiters. I am using php 4.3.8 on zach saws portable php server. I checked php's website and it says preg_match_all works for versions above 4

Comment: I also tried your code on phpfiddle.org now and it works fine there. Have you checked the content of $ips already?

Comment: yes that's one of the values [the log file is huge, just slightly different variations of that log line] of $ips before the $fixed array gets imploded into a string..

Comment: I also tested the script on our linux server with php 5.4 and I am getting the same blank array. :(

Comment: Regarding if `preg_match_all` accepts array input: [No, see manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) `string $subject `.

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
$file = file('log.txt');
$ips = implode($fixed);
```

should be:

```
$file = file('log.txt');
$ips = implode($file);
//              ^^^^
```

Comment: $fixed is an array that had an array map function done to it and an if statement to filter out ip addresses I dont need. I am beginning to wonder if preg_match_all is choking on extra spaces...

Comment: @Lid: Pleasr, edit your question to have an reproductible example. Add a `print_r($ips)`

Comment: I added the output of print_r($ips), the script works fine now, had to go through the filtering function to fix some of the comparison logic. I am a regex beginner, so I thought there was something wrong with that.